# How to insert into database using for loop

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to use for loop to insert data into database, and seems like there are no error in the code as the compiler doesn't prompt any error, but when I clicked into submit button, the data are not inserted

I only tried mysqli as it is most familiar by me

```
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','generator');

$statement = mysqli_query($db, 'SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()');

$order_id = mysqli_fetch_array($statement);

for($count=0; $count<$_POST["total_item"]; $count++)
{

    $statement = $db->prepare("
        INSERT INTO docgenitem
        (order_id, vendor, itemdescription, order_item_quantity, order_item_price, order_item_actual_amount )
        VALUES (:order_id, :vendor, itemdescription, :order_item_quantity, :order_item_price, :order_item_actual_amount)
    ");

    $statement->execute(
        array(
        ':order_id'               =>  $order_id,
        ':vendor'                 =>  trim($_POST["item_name"][$count]),
        ':itemdescription'          =>  trim($_POST["itemdescription"][$count]),
        ':quantity'          =>  trim($_POST["order_item_quantity"][$count]),
        ':priceperunit'          =>  trim($_POST["order_item_price"][$count]),
        ':amount'           =>  trim($_POST["order_item_final_amount"][$count]),
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: `prepare()` and `execute()` both return values... check them to make sure they are what you think they are.

Comment: `prepare` could be outside the loop too.

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to execute a query inside a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should be:

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost','root','','generator');

$order_id = $db->insert_id;

for($count=0; $count<$_POST["total_item"]; $count++)
{

    $s1 = trim($_POST["item_name"][$count]);
    $s2 = trim($_POST["itemdescription"][$count]);
    $s3 = trim($_POST["order_item_quantity"][$count]);
    $s4 = trim($_POST["order_item_price"][$count]);
    $s5 = trim($_POST["order_item_final_amount"][$count]);

    $statement = $db->prepare("
        INSERT INTO docgenitem
        (order_id, vendor, itemdescription, order_item_quantity, order_item_price, order_item_actual_amount )
        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    ");

    $statement->bind_param('dsssss', $order_id, $s1, $s2, $s3, $s4, $s5);
    $statement->execute();
}

$statement->close();

$db->close();
```

Comment: i have tried it, and an error occured saying Only variables should be passed by reference

Comment: @user7378014 Because `bind_param()` requires parameters to be passed by reference, and the result of `trim()` cannot be turned into a reference. You could assign variables to `trim()` functions outside/before the loop, then passed them into `bin_param()`. It will resolve the problem and speed-up the PHP code too.

Comment: can you show me an example, since I'm new into using bind_param

Comment: @user7378014 I've just edited my answer. The code will work properly now.

Comment: its says that it doesn't recognize $count

Comment: @user7378014 Oh yes! I forgot you using $count as array keys. The answer was updated! Absolutely no error now!

Comment: "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean" is what it said

Comment: You should check this database credentials: `$db = new mysqli('localhost','root','','generator');`. Change it to your database info, this code works properly in my server.